# Two Html.DropDownListFor for one Model property?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two select lists, and I want the selection for both to go to one property in the Model.

```
        <li>
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, (SelectList)fiscalYearsList, "All Years", new { id = "fiscalYearsList", style= "display:none" })
        </li>
        <li>
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, (SelectList)calendarYearsList, "All Years", new { id = "calendarYearsList" })
        </li>
```

Then with Jquery I am toggling each whenever a radio button is selected. Is this possible to send just the selected item from the visible DropDownListFor to the model? It is not quite working at the moment. Only the first DropDownListFor actually gets sent to the model.

Comment: I was being lazy, with this question. I ended up adding another property to my model and adding a little extra logic. Works fine.

Comment: How about posting your answer then?

Comment: My rep is < 100 so I have to wait 8 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding another property to my View Model and then adding a little extra logic to display the correct DropDownListFor with Javascript. Works fine.